# A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll in windows 7 but not on xp

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am having a bit of a problem with this code that works fine in Visual Basic 2010 Professional under Windows XP using .NET 4.0.  However, when this code runs on a Windows 7 machine, I get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> "An Unhandled Exception Of Type 'System.IO.IOException' Occurred In Mscorlib.dll"

The code I have written is used to write the content of a ListBox to a text file.

The problem is that the file is not created or when it is created manually, it is not read from  and this only happens in Windows 7.

This is the code I have written:

```
   'at the very top
   Imports System.Net
   Imports System
   Imports System.Windows.Forms
   Imports System.Security.Permissions
   
   'in my form load
   If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\hitory.txt") Then
        Dim h As New IO.StreamReader("C:\hitory.txt")
        While (h.Peek() > -1)
            history.ListBox1.Items.Add(h.ReadLine)
        End While
        h.Close()
    Else
        'charge l'historique en mémoire
        Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\hitory.txt")
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To history.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            w.WriteLine(history.ListBox1.Items.Item(i))
        Next
        w.Close()
    End If

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\fav.txt") Then
        Dim f As New IO.StreamReader("C:\fav.txt")
        While (f.Peek() > -1)
            fav.ListBox1.Items.Add(f.ReadLine)
        End While
        f.Close()
    Else
        'charge les favorit en mémoire
        Dim z As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\fav.txt")
        Dim j As Integer
        For j = 0 To fav.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            z.WriteLine(fav.ListBox1.Items.Item(j))
        Next
        z.Close()
    End If
    textBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\hitory.txt"))
```

Comment: check rights of the folder and the program running under; otherwise also check that virus scanner is not a bottle neck here.

Answer (score 2):

On the Windows 7 machine, UAC is kicking in. Your application does not have the appropriate privileges to write to files in the root level of the disk.

The bug was still there in Windows XP, it just wasn't being caught with your (default) security settings. Any competent system administrator would have configured the system to restrict access to the root level of the disk, and you'd be right back where you are under Windows 7.

There are only two possible fixes:

1. Add a manifest to your application that indicates it must be run with administrative privileges. This will cause UAC to prompt for elevation when the application is launched. If your user account has administrative privileges, you'll be able to elevate the process and then it will have the privileges to write to the root level of the disk. Otherwise, you're screwed—you can't even launch the app.

   This is the *wrong* choice. Your application **should not** be writing to the root level of the disk, so papering over the central bug by introducing a bunch of additional complexity is, frankly, stupid.
2. Fix the code so that it saves files some place else. The Application Data folder is a good place, unless the end user needs to be able to see/modify the files, then you want the My Documents folder.

   You get the path to these folders using the [`System.Environment.GetFolderPath` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx), which takes an eumeration value of type [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) that specifies the folder you want to retrieve the path to.

   Good choices are:

   - `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` for application-specific data that should roam with the user account.
   - `SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` for application-specific data that should *not* roam with the user account.
   - `SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` for documents created by the application that the user should be able to see/modify.

   Once you get the path, use the [`System.IO.Path.Combine` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to append your file name. Use *that* path instead to load/save the file.

Oh yeah, and spell the file name correctly: `history.txt`. :-)

Comment: yea but wouldn't an access violation throw an authorizedaccessexception and not an ioexception? :\ at first, i thought it might be a permissions issue, but now i'm sure it isn't ;o

Answer (score 0):

> "C:\hitory.txt"

typo is probably your issue. put the whole thing in a try, catch:

```
Try
    ' code
Catch ax As UnauthorizedAccessException
    MsgBox("ax: " & ax.ToString)
Catch ix As IO.IOException
    MsgBox("ix: " & ix.ToString)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("ex: " & ex.ToString)
End Try
```

and to append, specify the 'append' parameter. ie:

```
Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\history.txt", True)
```

also, why use My.Computer.FileSystem, and not System.IO? it's faster, less abstraction.

also, i don't like this peek stuff. i don't see a need for it in your case, see my other post here for StreamReader/Writer usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792819/vb-code-to-parse-one-file-into-two-files/23816245#23816245

or there's this other approach, which will return a String() array, which you can easily convert to a dataset or list for your listbox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
File.ReadAllLines("C:\history.txt")
```

edit: as codebased mentioned in comments (i can't write comments yet), permissions are a possible issue as well.

Comment: It is unlikely that the typo is the problem. He's *consistently* made the same typo, so the code that writes the file is actually writing to a file name `hitory.txt`. Therefore, the code that attempts reads the file should find it. Moreover, putting the whole thing in a try/catch is useless. The only thing you're doing in the catch block is showing a message box, which the default unhandled exception handler already does for you. That's how he knows he's getting an IOException. Finally, the talk of `System.IO` being "faster" is nonsense. There is no real world difference after optimizations.

Comment: there is no problem reading from root, problem writing on some systems. the reason for the try/catch statements was simply as an example obviously, not meant to be used in practice... normally you'd handle all errors gracefully by checking appropriate object states, and catching/logging/ignoring all other exceptions. also, not specifying a path simply uses the current folder, but you could use the appdata/temp folder. plus, if he copied it to root and is saying he can't read, then there's a problem, since authenticated users have read permissions for root. System.IO is faster, not by much.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\hitory.txt")*
```

This code says that you are opening a `StreamWriter` you need to close that before you can continue.
Add at the end of your coding `w.close()` before you do anything else with the fill. It is kind of like opening a movie and watching it. Then moving it somewhere else while it is still open. It will not work.